# Equality for anonymous types

Tags: c#, equality, anonymous-types

Why does the semantics of Equals() and == differs when used to compare anonymous types? Why does one compare values and the other compare references? What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`==` doesn't call `Equals`, it looks for `==` overloaded operator. Since anonymous types doesn't have overloaded `==` operator, so C# uses reference comparison for it.

But with `Equals` it compares field values. That is why the result between `==` and `Equals` differ.

[Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the
>   properties, **two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only
>   if all their properties are equal.**

Comment: Thanks! Under the hood, the C# compiler implements a sealed class for anonymous types. The reason as to why == compares references makes perfect sense to me. But Equals() comparing values for reference types doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I though only string was an exception when it came to comparing strings using Equals(). However, in the case of strings, it make sense.