# How are Equals and GetHashCode implemented on anonymous types?

Tags: c#, equals, anonymous-types, gethashcode

The Help says this:

> Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and
>   that cannot be cast to any type except object. The compiler provides a
>   name for each anonymous type, although your application cannot access
>   it. From the perspective of the common language runtime, an anonymous
>   type is no different from any other reference type.
>
> If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a
>   sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the
>   same names and types, the compiler treats the objects as instances of
>   the same type. They share the same compiler-generated type
>   information.
>
> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the
>   properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
>   all their properties are equal.

These things are true, but how? The reference source shows explicitly how objects are compared (`ReferenceEquals`) and a type that 'derives directly from object' cannot have this special behaviour. It doesn't match the behavour of `Equals` in `ValueType` either.

So how is it done? How can anonymous types override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` without any visible overrides?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The compiler generates the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` overrides for you. For example, from this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new { Text = "foo", Value = 17 };

        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

You can find the generated anonymous type in the compiled .exe, where the methods look like this (this is the output from dotPeek…there's also `ToString()`):

```
  [DebuggerHidden]
  public override string ToString()
  {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.Append("{ Text = ");
    stringBuilder.Append((object) this.\u003CText\u003Ei__Field);
    stringBuilder.Append(", Value = ");
    stringBuilder.Append((object) this.\u003CValue\u003Ei__Field);
    stringBuilder.Append(" }");
    return ((object) stringBuilder).ToString();
  }

  [DebuggerHidden]
  public override bool Equals(object value)
  {
    var fAnonymousType0 = value as \u003C\u003Ef__AnonymousType0<\u003CText\u003Ej__TPar, \u003CValue\u003Ej__TPar>;
    return fAnonymousType0 != null && EqualityComparer<\u003CText\u003Ej__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.\u003CText\u003Ei__Field, fAnonymousType0.\u003CText\u003Ei__Field) && EqualityComparer<\u003CValue\u003Ej__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.\u003CValue\u003Ei__Field, fAnonymousType0.\u003CValue\u003Ei__Field);
  }

  [DebuggerHidden]
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return -1521134295 * (-1521134295 * 512982588 + EqualityComparer<\u003CText\u003Ej__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(this.\u003CText\u003Ei__Field)) + EqualityComparer<\u003CValue\u003Ej__TPar>.Default.GetHashCode(this.\u003CValue\u003Ei__Field);
  }
```

Related reading:
[How does ToString on an anonymous type work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16794275)
[Why anonymous types Equals implementation compares fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12123512)
[Equality for anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23703846)
[Why is ValueType.GetHashCode() implemented like it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3841602)

None of those directly address your question, but they do provide some relevant insights into the specific implementations of these overrides.